# How can I extract outgoing links from a website in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def parsehttp(url):
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')


    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        href = link.attrs.get("href")
        print(href)
```

I would like to be able to extract all outgoing links from a website, however, the code that I have right now is returning both relative links and outgoing links and I only want the outgoing links. The difference is outgoing links has the https portion in them while relative ones do not. I also want to obtain the 'title' portion that comes with each link as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far to filter the links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^(http|https)://")}):
    href = link.attrs.get("href")
    if href is not None:
        print(href)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the first 5 characters of href are https to identify this:

```
if href[0:5] == "https":
   #outgoing link
else:
   #incoming link
```

Comment: basically it means its not getting any links. href has nothing inside. it didnt get a link at all. Have you tried printing href?

Comment: I did try to print it and that's when it returned the error, any suggestions? I'm sorry if this seems like a dumb mistake, I am still a beginner so please be patient.

Comment: I did try printing href on its own and it worked but when I went to check for href[0:5] and printing it again, it failed. I am sorry if this seems like a dumb mistake, I am still a beginner so any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: its alright. This method can only be used for strings. so its also possible that the href is stroring an object of another type. try using print(type(href)) to see what type it is

Answer (score 0):

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    href = link.attrs.get("href", "")
    if not href.startwith("https://"):
        continue
    
    print(href)
```